# Scale and duplicate a shape with in a shape at equal spacing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hey I am trying to scale and duplicate a circle placed at equal spaces Please help as I am an Illustrator beginner. Thanks

Comment: Not a bad question. But in reality you should at this point concentrate on the basic toolset instead of hoping there is a trick that makes this happen. Just copy paste in front move then scale and repeat the action. Why?  Well: 1. it gets you there.  2. It teaches you the tool set that always works. Regardless of knowing a pile of tricks you end up here every now and then. If you don't practice now its just harder when you are there 3. Illustrator at its core is just replacement for pen and paper. Illustrator does not really automate anything, Every trick just happens to work now, randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Offset Path:

Select the ellipse >> Go to the Object menu >> Go to the Path submenu >> Select Offset Path

You can also make actions for it to easily be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to scale and duplicate an object while maintaining equal spacing.

Probably the simplest is to select the circle and then Edit> Copy then Edit> Paste in Place. With the copy of the circle selected use the Selection tool (Black Arrow) and make sure View> Show Bounding Box is ticked on. Put your cursor in one of the corners of the Bounding Box and click drag to scale the circle copy. Holding the Shift key while dragging will maintain proportions.

If you Select your circle and click on the Scale Tool you can click drag to scale your circle. Also if you hit Enter with the scale tool selected it brings up a dialog box which allows you to specify the scaling percentage and scale the original object or scale a copy.

For more control you can also use Object> Transform> Scale with your circle selected. This brings up a dialog box with which you can scale and click copy at the bottom.

For even a bit more control you can go to Effect> Distort and Transform> Transform. This brings up a dialog where you can scale, move, rotate, and create as many copies of the effect as you want. This same dialog box is also available in the Appearance Panel (Window> Appearance). At the bottom of the panel click the Fx icon and choose transform.

It is worth noting that using an Effect, whether from the Effect menu or the FX in the Appearance panel will add an effect to your original shape which will be a "live" effect which you can later change or adjust by clicking the effect in the appearance panel. You must go to Object> Expand Appearance and then Object >Ungroup (maybe a couple times) to turn your Effects into individual shapes.

It is worth looking into all these different options and learning how they work. They all have their benefits and uses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach which will work for concentric circles.

1. Click and  hold the Line Segment tool, and the other tools will pop up. Select the Polar Grid tool.

[image]

2. Double click the tool in the toolbar, and set the radial divider value to 0, set the concentric dividers to as many circles as you need.

[image]

3. Click and drag the tool while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain it to an exact circle.

[image]

Comment: Or perhaps consecutive offsets. Thing is though the question is a bit vague. I interpret the that the circles are side by side not concentric. But again, this is a trick. It does not ultimately help is the situation is not circles.

Comment: @joojaa "a shape with in a shape" should probably be "a shape within a shape" which  suggests concentric circles to me.